# Rotate points like a galaxy

Tags: java

I've been working on a program which takes in 3 numbers as a seed, and uses those numbers to generate points like so:

[image: Generated Points]

If you zoom in closely on the image, you will see there are a lot of streaks which expand straight out from the center, I was wondering how I could rotate the points around the center to have it look like a galaxy?

I'm using the BufferedImage library in Java to output the image.

Comment: What language, what platform?

Comment: You could try a logarithmic spiral, like this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSpiral.html

Comment: I updated the original question, I'm using Java.

The logarithmic spiral looks like the way to go, however wouldn't all the points be along a single line?

Comment: You can split your points into n subsets and create n spirals and rotate them so they have a starting difference of 2pi/n.

Comment: I've stored the values in two arrays, one is for the angle and the other is for the radius. I then convert from polar to rectangular coordinates to plot the points. Would I just multiply the values in the angle array by (2pi/n)*spiral number?

Comment: As an aside, galaxies have an amazing variety of shapes, not every one is symmetrical and they can have weird features like central bars: http://www.galaxyzoo.org/